# Using Animations On Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When I use a page animation to navigate from one page to another, I navigate fine to the second page but I can't navigate back to the main page (using the hardware back button) .When I try to navigate back I find all controls on the page gone.

Code to go the second page

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Run animation then navigate to second page
        myAnimation.Begin();
        myAnimation.Completed += (s,ev)=>
          {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextPage.xaml?id=Button1",UriKind.Relative));
          };

    }
```

Code on second page

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e )
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            myAnimation.Begin();   //Another Animation     
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your storyboard moves the controls outside of the view. When the user presses the back button, the previous page is restored in the exact state you left it. So the controls are still be hidden from the view.

To solve the issue, simply reset the storyboard when the user navigates to the page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    myAnimation.Stop();
}
```